# Extending Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using the latest version of Bootstrap, and I'm looking for some help with the tabs. Here's what I'm looking to do...

I have a link located in the header of my site. When clicked, the viewer would be taken to the Rules tab, located on the bottom of the content area. The Rules tab should be selected and ready to go.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="" title="Rules">Click to read the rules</a>
</div> <!-- end header -->

<div id="content">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rules">Rules</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="rules">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end content -->
```

JS:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="#" title="Rules">Click to read the rules</a>
</div> <!-- end header -->

<div id="content">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#rules">Rules</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">1...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">2...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="rules">3...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">4...</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end content -->
```

**JS**

```
$('#header a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myTab a[href="#rules"]').tab('show'); 
});
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/fWV7Z/

Comment: I was wondering, if I was to do this for more than 1 tab... is there a way I can combine the click function code, or would I have to write one out for each tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#header a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   $('#rules').tab('show');  // or $('#rules').click();
});
```